# How to return a list from a ThreadPoolExecutor process in Python

Tags: python, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to return a list from a ThreadPoolExecutor process in Python, but the list, in this case "works", just remains empty after it finishes running.

The rest of the code works (mostly, because as well, it will sometimes sporadically spit out an "malloc: Incorrect checksum" or "segmentation fault" error, when I try and pull from too many clases).

Either way, I need to be able to put all the results from each loop into one list and have that be returned at the end of the main function.

I have modified the code based on the comments, just to make it as simple as possible.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account as sa
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import time
import concurrent.futures as cf

key = 'test.json'
email = 'jj@school.com'

works = []

scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students",
]

cr = sa.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
  key, scopes=scopes).with_subject(email)

sh = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=cr).spreadsheets()
cl = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=cr)


def listClasses():
  semdate = "2020/08/01"
  cr1 = datetime.strptime(semdate, '%Y/%m/%d').date()
  pr1 = "profe@school.edu.mx"
  arr1 = []

  re1 = cl.courses().list(
    teacherId=pr1,
    courseStates="ACTIVE"
    ).execute()
  courses = re1.get('courses', [])

  for i in courses:
    ct = i['creationTime'][:10].replace("-","/")
    cr2 = datetime.strptime(ct,'%Y/%m/%d').date()
    ci = i['id']
    if cr2 > cr1:
      arr1.append(ci)

  return arr1


def lcw(i):
    res1= cl.courses().courseWork().list(courseId=i).execute()
    works = res1.get('courseWork', [])
    if len(works) != 0:
      return works 


def main():
  lcs = listClasses()  

  start = time.perf_counter()

  with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as excut:
    x = excut.map(lcw,lcs)
    y = [i.result() for i in x]
    print(y)

  fin = time.perf_counter()
  print(f"Done in {round(fin-start, 2)} seconds")
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Just pass in the `result` method. 
`x = excut.map(lcw, lcs)` and then `y = [i.result() for i in x]`

Comment: for some reason, adding that returns an error. If I put: with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as excut: x = excut.map(lcw,lcs) and then y = [i.result() for i in x] and try to print it, I get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'result' ", but there are results. So, still not working.

Comment: Or, I get this error: "socket.timeout: The read operation timed out"